# kableextra colnames lineabreak after a specific character in R

Tags: r, r-markdown, kableextra

I have table below:

```
mydf <- data.frame(col0 =c(rep("z",5)),col1= c(rep(0,5)), col2= c(rep(1,5)))
colnames(mydf) <- c("name","aaaa, bbbb", "ccccccc, ddddd-dd")

mynames <- sapply(c(colnames(mydf)), FUN = function(x) gsub("," , ",\\\\", x))
kbl(mydf,
    escape=F,
    col.names = linebreak(mynames))
```

I want my column names to break to the next line after "`,`" (comma). I tried `",\\\\"`, `",\\"` and `",\n"`. none is working. I m producing an r markdown pdf-output. 
any suggestions or hints?

Comment: Are you sure it is not working in `pdf` with `mynames <- gsub(",", "\n", names(mydf))`  I tried and it seems to be working fine in Rmarkdown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may use the `HTML` tag (`"<br>"`) to create the line break for HTML files - `gsub/sub` are vectorized, so there is no need to loop over each element of the column names

```
library(kableExtra)
mynames <- gsub(",", "<br>", names(mydf))
kbl(mydf,
    escape=FALSE,
    col.names = linebreak(mynames))
```

---

If it is a pdf file, the following could work

```
mynames <- gsub("[,-]", "\n", names(mydf))
```

-full code - rmarkdown

````
---
title: "."
output: bookdown::pdf_document2
---



```{r chunk1, echo = FALSE}
library(kableExtra)
mydf <- data.frame(col0 =c(rep("z",5)),col1= c(rep(0,5)), col2= c(rep(1,5)))
colnames(mydf) <- c("name","aaaa, bbbb", "ccccccc, ddddd-dd")
mynames <- gsub(",", "\n", names(mydf))

kbl(mydf,
   escape=FALSE,
   col.names = linebreak(mynames))

```
````

-output

[image]

Comment: Thanks but it does not move to next line when I knit mt rmarkdown to pdf. it just replace , with <br>

Comment: @Mathica Sorry, I thought it was HTML

Comment: @Mathica I updated with the pdf output I am getting. Can you test the code

Comment: It is working on a machine and not on another! hmmm I must see what s wrong here.